# how to set windows phone system's wallpaper in code?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to set the system's wallpaper by code in c#,but havn't found any classes or api about it.Can anyone know it?

Comment: Could explain, what do you mean by "wallpaper"? Background image for page, panorama, etc. Or splash-screen which showing when application starting?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't change the phone's wallpaper by code. A few homebrew apps manage to do it with some hacks, but it requires an unlocked phone and it will fail marketplace certification.